# Solutions to $\phi(f) = 0$ when $\phi$ is a 2d discrete convolution.

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, convolution

This is a special case of a [previous question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2157514/167108), which I hope will receive more attention due to the specificity.

Suppose we have a function space $F = \{f : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb R\}$ and a discrete convolution $\phi : F \to F$ given by
$$\phi(f) = p \mapsto \sum_{\delta \in \mathbb Z^2}\gamma_\delta f(p - \delta)$$
where $\gamma \in \mathbb R[\mathbb Z^2]$ is an element of the group ring of reals indexed by the 2d integer lattice. (We may treat $\gamma$ simply as a finitely-supported map $\gamma : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb R$, so that the sum defining $\phi(f)$ above makes sense: the sum becomes a finite sum since only finitely many $\gamma_\delta$ are nonzero.) We place a condition on $\gamma$: the support of $\gamma$ must generate $\mathbb Z^2$ (as a group), so that the kernel of $\phi$ is not made of infinitely many equivalent "slices".

I am trying to prove the following conjecture:

**Conjecture:** If $\phi(f) = 0$ then $f$ is either the zero function or has infinite support.

For convenience let $F_{fin} \leq F$ be the subspace of finitely-supported functions in $F$.

One plan I have is to show that $\ker \phi$ is finite-dimensional, since if $\ker \phi$ is finite-dimensional then $\ker \phi \cap F_{fin}$ must also be finite-dimensional, and it is not hard to see that $\ker \phi \cap F_{fin}$ must have dimension either 0 or $\infty$ (since if $\phi(f) = 0$ with $f$ finitely supported, then for any translate $f'$ of $f$, still $\phi(f') = 0$ but for infinitely many $f'$ we have $f'$ linearly independent from $f$).

However, I am not yet able to show that $\ker \phi$ is finite-dimensional.

Can anyone prove the finite-dimensionality of $\ker \phi$? Or perhaps solve the conjecture a different way?

Comment: if $\phi(f)=f(x,y+1)-f(x,y)$, $\ker(\phi)$ is the set of all maps ${\mathbb Z}^2 \to {\mathbb R}$ that depend only on the first variable. This space is not finite-dimensional.

Comment: Oh, I forgot a condition: the support of $\gamma$ should generate $\mathbb Z^2$, to disallow cases like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give it a try:

If $\gamma:\>{\mathbb Z}^2\to{\mathbb C}$ has finite support then
$$\hat\gamma(x,y):=\sum_{k, l}\gamma(k,l)e^{2\pi i(kx+ly)}$$
is a trigonometric polynomial in the variables $x$ and $y$.  Furthermore, if $f:\>{\mathbb Z}^2\to{\mathbb C}$ has finite support then $\hat f(x,y)$ is a trigonometric polynomial as well. Now one computes
$$\eqalign{\widehat{\phi(f)}(x,y)&=\sum_{k,l}\phi(f)(k,l)e^{2\pi i(kx+ly)}\cr
&=\sum_{k,l}\left(\sum_{r,s}\gamma(r,s)f(k-r,l-s)\right)e^{2\pi i(kx+ly)}\cr
&=\sum_{r,s}\sum_{k',l'}\gamma(r,s)f(k',l')e^{2\pi i((k'+r)x+(l'+s)y)}\cr
&=\hat\gamma(x,y)\>\hat f(x,y)\ .\cr}$$
If we now had $\phi(f)=0$ then this would imply $\widehat{\phi(f)}(x,y)\equiv0$. On the other hand, the product of two nonzero trigonometric polynomials cannot be identically $0$.

Note that I did not use your technical assumption on $\gamma$.